# I have a major problem with my C++ Program

Tags: c++

For an assignment, I need to read in multiple sections followed by percentages. For example,

```
2 80 97
5 69 79 89 99 58
7 60 70 80 90 100 0 59
```

(2 being the number of percentages in a section, and so forth)

My program reads the first line perfectly fine, but then skips over the 5, reads in "69" as the next amount of percentages in the next section, and completely screws up.

Here is my code:

```
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Name: ******
    //
    // Course: ********
    //
    // Purpose: To produce grading summaries by section, sorted by amount of
    // each letter grade, highest/lowest percentages and the average, as well
    // as the class averages, amount of sections and scores at the end
    //
    // Input: Prompted without text--the number of scores in a section, and
    // then the percentages within the section. Inputs are recieved until EOF
    //
    // Output: Amount of each letter grade, highest/lowest percentages
    // and the average, the class averages, amount of sections and scores
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    //Initialize global variables for each letter grade, as well as the
    //'reset' variables so the variables can be reset after each section
    //is completed computing
    const int A = 90, B = 80, C = 70, D = 60, RESET = 0, LSRESET = 100;

    //Initializes the Main Function
    int main()
    {
       //Makes sure output does not exceed two decimal places
       cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

       //Initialize all int and float variables
      int loopCount = 0, percentage = 0, scoreCount = 0,
       sectionSize = 0, sectionCount = 0, aCount = 0, bCount = 0, cCount = 0,
       dCount = 0, fCount = 0, lowestScore = 100, highestScore = 0;
       float averageScore = 0, total = 0, classAverage = 0;

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
       //Primes the outer while loop
       cin >> sectionSize;
       cout << endl;
       //Outer while loop for each section
       while (cin)
       {
          sectionCount++;
          cin >> percentage;
          //Inner while loop to compute number of each letter grade,
          //conditions are until the section size is equal to the loop count
          while (loopCount != sectionSize)
          {
             //Simple if statements to see what letter grade
             //the percentage inputted falls into
             if (percentage >= A)
             {
                aCount++;
             }
             else if (percentage < A && percentage >= B)
             {
                bCount++;
             }
             else if (percentage < B && percentage >= C)
             {
                cCount++;
             }
             else if (percentage < C && percentage >= D)
             {
                dCount++;
             }
             else if (percentage < D)
             {
                fCount++;
             }

             //Increase the inner loop count and score count
             //so it can be used for future calculations
             loopCount++;
             scoreCount++;

             //Sets percentage to highest score or lowest score
             //when applicable
             if (percentage > highestScore)
             {
                highestScore = percentage;
             }
             if (percentage < lowestScore)
             {
                lowestScore = percentage;
             }

             //Compute the total score
             total = percentage + total;

             //Takes in the next number and sets it to the percentage
             cin >> percentage;
          }
          averageScore = total / sectionSize;
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
          //Cout statements to print number of each letter grade,
          //as well as low/high scores and the average
         cout << "Scores for section " << sectionCount << endl;
          cout << "A's: " << aCount << endl;
          cout << "B's: " << bCount << endl;
          cout << "C's: " << cCount << endl;
          cout << "D's: " << dCount << endl;
          cout << "F's: " << fCount << endl;
          cout << "Lowest Score: " << lowestScore << endl;
          cout << "Highest Score: " << highestScore << endl;
          cout << "Average Score: " << averageScore << endl << endl << endl;

          //Resets variables that need to be reset after the loop is
          //finished
          aCount = RESET;
          bCount = RESET;
          cCount = RESET;
          dCount = RESET;
          fCount = RESET;
          lowestScore = LSRESET;
          highestScore = RESET;
          averageScore = RESET;
          total = RESET;
          loopCount = RESET;

          //Begins to compute the class average

          classAverage = classAverage + total;



          cin >> sectionSize;
       }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
       //Finishes computing the class average
       classAverage = classAverage / sectionCount;

       //Cout statements with final calculations and termination
       cout << "Total number of sections: " << sectionCount << endl;
       cout << "Total number of scores: " << scoreCount << endl;
       cout << "Class Average: " << classAverage << endl << endl;
       cout << "That's all the sections!! Normal Termination." << endl;
       return 0;
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have been working on trying to fix this issue for so long now, someone please help. I've asked my professor and my peers to which the problem still couldn't be solved.

Comment: Do you know how to use your debugger? That's not an empty question - if you don't know how we may be able to give you some pointers.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: I'm still fairly new to developing and am in a beginner's C++ class right now. They never taught us how to use the debugger

Comment: Well we're going to fix that RIGHT NOW. What IDE are you using? (do you know what an IDE is?)

Comment: Learning how to do this (use the debugger you probably already have) now yourself will greatly help you in the future. It will not only help you write better code but also help you get the work done faster.

Comment: I'm using Xcode. I've tried tracing through my code a bunch and can't figure out for the life of me why it is skipping over a number

Comment: Which is why we're suggesting using your debugger. I don't use xcode myself so I can't speak about it directly, but the apple website seems pretty straightforward: [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html) The main functionality you want from a debugger is to 1. set breakpoints (your code will pause here), 2. step through your program (you can usually step to the next line, step into functions, and step over functions), and 3. OBSERVE VARIABLES.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the start of main. Run your debugger. Single step through the program and observe how your variables change. Just sit and watch. See what happens. Are you variables changing in the same way you expect them to? Are branches of your program being entered the same way you expect them to? If not, then THAT'S a good specific question to search for/ask on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Another useful tool (in addition to a debugger) is the mythical [mre]. Focus on one error, and remove everything that is not needed to reproduce it. In your case, you identified a problem reading from a file, so get rid of all of those calculations -- the only "calculation" you should need is the number of percentages to read. The only output you might need is writing exactly what you read from the file. Get rid of the extraneous trappings so your bug has no place to hide.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you're performin "cin >> percentage;" "sectionSize + 1" times.

So the corrected version would look like:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: ******
//
// Course: ********
//
// Purpose: To produce grading summaries by section, sorted by amount of
// each letter grade, highest/lowest percentages and the average, as well
// as the class averages, amount of sections and scores at the end
//
// Input: Prompted without text--the number of scores in a section, and
// then the percentages within the section. Inputs are recieved until EOF
//
// Output: Amount of each letter grade, highest/lowest percentages
// and the average, the class averages, amount of sections and scores
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Initialize global variables for each letter grade, as well as the
//'reset' variables so the variables can be reset after each section
//is completed computing
const int A = 90, B = 80, C = 70, D = 60, RESET = 0, LSRESET = 100;

//Initializes the Main Function
int main()
{
   //Makes sure output does not exceed two decimal places
   cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

   //Initialize all int and float variables
  int loopCount = 0, percentage = 0, scoreCount = 0,
   sectionSize = 0, sectionCount = 0, aCount = 0, bCount = 0, cCount = 0,
   dCount = 0, fCount = 0, lowestScore = 100, highestScore = 0;
   float averageScore = 0, total = 0, classAverage = 0;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
   //Primes the outer while loop
   cin >> sectionSize;
   cout << endl;
   //Outer while loop for each section
   while (cin)
   {
      sectionCount++;
      // cin >> percentage;
      //Inner while loop to compute number of each letter grade,
      //conditions are until the section size is equal to the loop count
      while (loopCount != sectionSize)
      {
         cin >> percentage;

         //Simple if statements to see what letter grade
         //the percentage inputted falls into
         if (percentage >= A)
         {
            aCount++;
         }
         else if (percentage < A && percentage >= B)
         {
            bCount++;
         }
         else if (percentage < B && percentage >= C)
         {
            cCount++;
         }
         else if (percentage < C && percentage >= D)
         {
            dCount++;
         }
         else if (percentage < D)
         {
            fCount++;
         }

         //Increase the inner loop count and score count
         //so it can be used for future calculations
         loopCount++;
         scoreCount++;

         //Sets percentage to highest score or lowest score
         //when applicable
         if (percentage > highestScore)
         {
            highestScore = percentage;
         }
         if (percentage < lowestScore)
         {
            lowestScore = percentage;
         }

         //Compute the total score
         total = percentage + total;

         //Takes in the next number and sets it to the percentage
         // cin >> percentage;
      }
      averageScore = total / sectionSize;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
      //Cout statements to print number of each letter grade,
      //as well as low/high scores and the average
     cout << "Scores for section " << sectionCount << endl;
      cout << "A's: " << aCount << endl;
      cout << "B's: " << bCount << endl;
      cout << "C's: " << cCount << endl;
      cout << "D's: " << dCount << endl;
      cout << "F's: " << fCount << endl;
      cout << "Lowest Score: " << lowestScore << endl;
      cout << "Highest Score: " << highestScore << endl;
      cout << "Average Score: " << averageScore << endl << endl << endl;

      //Resets variables that need to be reset after the loop is
      //finished
      aCount = RESET;
      bCount = RESET;
      cCount = RESET;
      dCount = RESET;
      fCount = RESET;
      lowestScore = LSRESET;
      highestScore = RESET;
      averageScore = RESET;
      total = RESET;
      loopCount = RESET;

      //Begins to compute the class average

      classAverage = classAverage + total;



      cin >> sectionSize;
   }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
   //Finishes computing the class average
   classAverage = classAverage / sectionCount;

   //Cout statements with final calculations and termination
   cout << "Total number of sections: " << sectionCount << endl;
   cout << "Total number of scores: " << scoreCount << endl;
   cout << "Class Average: " << classAverage << endl << endl;
   cout << "That's all the sections!! Normal Termination." << endl;
   return 0;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, learning to use a debugger would be really useful. Or, an even simpler process: you could put prints in your code.

Comment: Oh my god you are a lifesaver. Thank you so much, I can't believe I didn't try that. And yeah I plan on trying to learn about debugging

Comment: @isuckatprogramming: If you determined that the answer solved your problem, please accept it.